# VB.NET - How to know if a mail sent through app has been received

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, pop3

I have an app made with .NET Framework 3.5 The app sends an Html eMail to a list of customers. My problem is that I can know if the mail wasn't generated or sended, but after send I don't know anything about the mail. I was thinking on using some scheduled task to check my inbox or something like that, but I think that there could be a better and easier solution. Besides, I couldn't get access to my gmail inbox... So my question is how can I know if a mail it's received after it's sended through my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed a tracking image in your email.

Create a service to track whenever the image is displayed (by serving the image based on a request id uniquely mapped to each email recipient's email address.)

When the service serves up the image, per "user", you know a given email has been opened.

Write a report to tell you which emails have/haven't been opened.

Comment: Note that many email readers are set to ignore images due to band width and possibly hacking. If so you don't know whether the email has been opened.  There *might* be a flag to set to ask the recipient for a receipt. You can also use a service for tracking; they do it for a living and probably do a much better job than you ever will. They are not fool proof. I guess you can find such a service gratis. "Monkey"-something springs to mind, if nothing else they have a super copy writer.  Finally: use Papercut for debugging email sending.